# PHP, MySQL; GROUP BY doesn't work for datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, group-by

I have some `datetime`'s in my MySQL database like this:

```
2016-11-15 10:00:00
2016-11-16 10:00:00
2016-11-17 10:00:00
2016-11-17 12:00:00
2016-11-17 19:30:00
2016-11-20 10:00:00
2016-12-15 10:00:00
2017-11-15 10:22:00
```

I want to output, but only once per day. That means:

```
2016-11-15 10:00:00
2016-11-16 10:00:00
2016-11-17 10:00:00
2016-11-20 10:00:00
2016-12-15 10:00:00
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT date_db FROM my_table GROUP BY DATE(date_db) ORDER BY date_db');
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {

    echo "<option value=\"".$row['date_db']."\">".$row['date_db']."</option>";
}
?>
```

But this doesn't really work. Some days simply are missing. Why that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use DISTINCT in your query?

Comment: @Naruto Do you mean: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT date_db FROM my_table ORDER BY date_db');`? Does't work.

Comment: That query will only select dates that exist on the database. Your results are correct as per the database. Your query will not INVENT data (dates) that do not exist

Comment: I assume you want all the dates between 2016-11-15 and 2016-12-15. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I want to have all days, but only once. That means, if there's `2016-11-16 10:00:00` and `2016-11-16 15:30:00` I want to have shown only `2016-11-16 10:00:00` because it's the same day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126087/discussion-between-david-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code now:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT date_db FROM my_table GROUP BY DATE(date_db) ORDER BY date_db');
$stmt->execute(array(':date' => $date));

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {

echo "<option value=\"".$row['date_db']."\">".$row['date_db']."</option>";
}
?>
```

I don't know why it's working now, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT MIN(date_db) FROM my_table GROUP BY DATE(date_db) ORDER BY DATE(date_db)
```